# TypeError: "hypothesis" expects pre-tokenized hypothesis (Iterable[str]):

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, metrics

I am trying to calculate the Meteor score for the following:

```
print (nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(
    ["this is an apple", "that is an apple"], "an apple on this tree"))
```

However I am getting this error every time and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
TypeError: "hypothesis" expects pre-tokenized hypothesis (Iterable[str]): an apple on this tree
```

I also tried to put "an apple on this tree" in a list

```
    from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score
import nltk 
print (nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(
    ["this is an apple", "that is an apple"], ["an apple on this tree"]))
```

but it gave me this error.

```
TypeError: "reference" expects pre-tokenized reference (Iterable[str]): this is an apple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the library code, it looks like hypothesis should be an iterable. https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/meteor_score.html. The error is coming from:

```
if isinstance(hypothesis, str):
        raise TypeError(
            f'"hypothesis" expects pre-tokenized hypothesis (Iterable[str]): {hypothesis}'
        )
```

Try putting "an apple on this tree" in a list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried putting "an apple on this tree" in a list but I am getting this error now. 

"TypeError: "reference" expects pre-tokenized reference (Iterable[str]): this is an apple"

The code is here:

from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score
import nltk 
print (nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(
    ["this is an apple", "that is an apple"], ["an apple on this tree"]))

Any advice please ?

Comment: The references argument in the meteor_score function is defined as `references: Iterable[Iterable[str]]`. so it should be a 2D array. Try putting another set of square brackets around the first argument: `[["this is an apple", "that is an apple"]]`

Comment: Thank you so much! that works when i have it 2D array.

[["this is an apple", "that is an apple"]], ["an apple on this tree"]))

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe the right answer for the problem is to tokenize the sentence before calling the function. For example:

```
    for line in zip(refs, hypos):
        ref = word_tokenize(line[0])
        hypo = word_tokenize(line[1])
        m_score += meteor_score([ref], hypo)
```

Where ref and hypo is a sentence string.